# Assert Method not reached in Try-Catch statement

Tags: c#, mstest

I am trying to unit test my code to see if I try to view an account's details without a sessionKey, it will throw an exception. The unit test will go and execute the statement in the try-catch and despite knowing an exception will occur, it lists the test as successful even though Assert should be false. Assert is reached in similar functions, but not always. What would be the cause of the problem?

Original Function

```
/// <summary>
/// Displays the account details to the user
/// </summary>
/// <returns>HttpResponseMessage deserialized into AccountResponses object</returns>
public async Task<AccountResponse> Details()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Session-Key", sessionKey);

    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(_baseUrl + "/Account/Details");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string details = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        AccountResponse temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccountResponse>(details);
        return temp
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Working Live Unit Test Function

```
[TestCategory("Account/Logon")]
[TestMethod]
public void LogOnNegativeBadPasswordTest()
{
    try
    {
        string sessionKey = dmWeb.Account.LogOn(new DMWeb_REST.AccountLogOn { Password = "test#pasasdfasfsword" }).GetAwaiter().GetResult().ToString();
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(ex.Message.Contains("400"));
    }
}
```

Not Working Live Unit Test Function

```
[TestCategory("Account/Details")]
[TestMethod]
public void DisplayDetailsNegativeNoSessionKeyTest()
{
    try
    {
        string details = dmWeb.Account.Details().GetAwaiter().GetResult().ToString();
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(ex.Message.Contains("401"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your code _in_ the question, not on imgur.

Comment: Please post code, not screenshots of your IDE. And include the exception message in your question.

Comment: Question: Why do you have a catch-block with simply `throw ex;` in it? What is the point of even wrapping the code above in a try/catch block *at all*?

Comment: Also, you should probably mock out your dependency on `HttpClient`, to avoid being caught by odd problems around trying to talk to odd servers, if that's not what you're trying to test.

Comment: Thirdly, it seems you're trying to test a negative, by expecting the code to actually throw an exception, in that it isn't authorized. But what if the code succeeds? Meaning you have a bug! Then the `details` variable will be populated and the test method returns normally, *normally* indicating success. You're probably missing something like `Assert.Fail` after your line inside the try-block, to make sure your code doesn't accidentally succeed.

Answer (score 0):

The test will be treated as successful as long as no errors are thrown. If no error is being caught in the `catch` block, this almost definitely means that no error was thrown by the code you're testing.

So place an `Assert.Fail()` after the statement that's supposed to throw an error:

```
public void TestMethod()
{
    try
    {
        string details = ThingIAmTesting();
        // shouldn't get here
        Assert.Fail();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(ex.Message.Contains("401");
    }
}
```